# Make does not run ar and make new libraries after object changes

Tags: c, makefile

Iam trying to start project with couple of static libraries that are built on their own makefiles, like this:

```
LIBDIR= ../../lib/
SRC= mgui.c

-include $(SRC:%.c=%.d)

INC=-I../../inc \
    -Iinc \
    -I../../shared

EXEC= libmgui.lib

CFLAGS= -Wall -static -D$(DEBUG) -MMD -MP

ARFLAGS= rcs
AR = ar

all: $(SRC:%.c=%.o)
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $(LIBDIR)$(EXEC) $<

%.o: %.c 
$(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(INC) $(CFLAGS)
```

That makefile is run from higher level makefile.

I have globals.h file in ../../shared/ folder, which is included from mgui.c and if I make modifications to that file, this makefile does not work. It just makes new .o file, but ar and new .lib is never made , why ? Using win8 with mingw.

Generated dependency file looks like this:

mgui.o: mgui.c inc/mgui.h ../../shared/globals.h

inc/mgui.h:

../../shared/globals.h:

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the `-include` down to the end of your makefile.  Make takes the first target defined (even if it's in an included file) and uses it as the default target.  Since the `include` comes first, it defines the `mgui.o` as the first target and that's the only target that will be built, unless you explicitly run `make all`.

Also, you shouldn't put the recipe to build the library in the `all` target rule.  If you do, then that library will always be rebuilt even if nothing has changed.

You should write it as:

```
all: $(LIBDIR)$(EXEC)

$(LIBDIR)$(EXEC): $(SRC:%.c=%.o)
        $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $<
```

Comment: Ah yes, ofcourse that did it, thank you ! I had that include at the end of makefile at some point, but there was something else wrong and then as I tried everything I was totally lost.